# Finding the minimum cardinal value of intersection of 4 sets.

Tags: combinatorics

**In a battle, 70% of the combatants lost one eye, 80% an ear, 75% an arm, 85% a leg, x% lost all the four limbs. Find the minimum value of x.**

So, this is related to **Classic Set Theory by George Cantor**.

As far I've tried the minimum number is the **intersection** of two set and the maximum number is the set having the **lowest cardinal number**. But, in this case, there are four sets, so that doesn't seem to work.

To approach the number, I tried making Venn Diagrams, but that's way too complicated for it.

Now, I'm clueless. I don't have any idea how to get this done, I doubt perhaps my approach was wrong.

Answer Given in Textbook is = 10.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just go step by step.  Looking at eye/ear we see that $≥50\%$ lost both.  Then, adding in arm, we see that $≥25\%$ must have lost eye/ear/arm.  Continuing....

Comment: @lulu didn't get your logic, please elaborate

Comment: No, this really doesn't relate to Cantor's set theory. This is a basic question in combinatorics. Not everything that is a set, or can be described via a Venn diagram is related to set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I noticed that too, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every 100 combactants,

Given,
$$ n(eye) = 70,$$
$$ n(ear) = 80,$$

So, as we know, the Minimum number of two non-empty sets can be Calculated using the Intersection Formula.

So,
$$ n(eye \cap ear) = n(eye) + n(ear) - n(U) $$
$$ = 70 + 80 - 100$$
(As we know $n(U)$ = 100, as calculations are being done for every 100 combactants, where 100 refers to Universal Set of all the 100 combactants)
$$ = 50 $$

Now, let Set $ eye \cap ear$ be set A.

So, the minimum number of Combatants who have got their eyes, ears and arm can be represented as $A \cap arm$

Thus,
$$ n(A \cap arm) = n(A) + n(arm) - n(U) $$
(Again, here U refers to Universal Set which contains all the hundred Combactants)
$$ = 50 + 75 - 100 $$
$$ = 25 $$

Thus, the minimum number of Combatants which have got their Eyes, Ears, and Arms Injured are 25.

Now, Let Set C be the set of the Minimum number of Combatants which have lost their Eyes, Ears, and Arms.

So, as we know, the minimum number of people who have lost all four will be $ C \cap leg $

Thus,
$$ n(C \cap leg) = n(C) + n(leg) - n(U) $$
$$= 25 + 85 - 100$$
$$= 110 - 100$$
$$ = 10 $$

Thus, The minimum possible Combatants which have lost all four are 10.

Comment: Leave an empty line if you want something on separate lines. Also, you need to define $U$ if you want to use it. And you should define $A$ to be the set of combatants which have lost Eye and Ear, and then reason about the minimum possible size of $A$. This is best expressed using an inequality: $n(A) \ge n(Eye)+n(Ear)-n(U)$. Likewise for the rest. Finally, $50\% = 0.50$, and if $n(S)$ denotes the size of set $S$ then you definitely do not have $n(A) \ge 50$ but rather $n(A) \ge 50\%·n(U)$.

Comment: But, good first attempt at a proof!

Comment: @user21820 I've improved the answer and added details according to your advice. Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't use an inequality, your statements are incorrect. Also, to prove the general result you must cater for all possible $n(U)$ and not just $n(U) = 100$. So you should stick to what I wrote in my comment; keep the stuff as percentages times $n(U)$. To make thing easier, you could first define $m = n(U)$ and then you would have $n(A) \ge 0.5m$.

Comment: @user21820 I didn't Use inequalities because we are taking about Lowest Possible Value. For example, the lowest number of arranging the Rubix Cube such that the red remains with the Blue one is $x$. But, when I say the number of arranging the Rubix cube such that red remains with Blue one are $ \ge x$. :) Also, at the first part I've mentioned we are working for every 100 soldiers, that implies, we have Universal Set of Soldiers and number of elements in it is 100

Comment: You're wrong. You did not define $eye$ and $ear$ in such a way that your statements are correct. Also, you cannot **assume** that the total number is $100$ because it was **nowhere** stated in the question.

Comment: @user21820 I understand what are you trying to say, feel free to edit the answer if you think it's a great issue.

Comment: It is your answer, and I am telling you how to make it correct, which you can do so by following what I said. Currently it is wrong. This has nothing to do with what I think. Mathematically it is objectively wrong. You can of course choose to ignore my advice...

Comment: @user21820 I respect your opinion, that wrong things should be corrected, but in my case, I'm not able to mathematically express certain things, which is inside my mind, so I asked you if you could help.

Comment: Like this: "Let U be the set of all ..." (and don't assume anything about its size). And from my first comment: "define A to be the set of combatants which have lost Eye and Ear, and then reason about the minimum possible size of A. This is best expressed using an inequality: n(Eye⋂Ear) ≥ n(Eye)+n(Ear)−n(U)". Likewise, "n(A⋂Leg) ≥ n(A)+n(Leg)−n(U)" and so on. Then you can see **precisely** why the argument works, because the inequalities can be added.

Comment: I'm afraid, I've not read inequalities till now, we are learning Complex Numbers now

Comment: If you want to learn mathematics properly, you will have to learn the tools you need, whether or not your teacher has taught them to you. "x ≥ y" just means "x is more than or equal to y". And there is a simple identity "n(S⋂T)+n(S⋃T) = n(S)+n(T)", which you can verify easily, and a simple inequality "n(S⋃T) ≤ n(U)". Together they give you "n(S⋂T)+n(U) ≥ n(S)+n(T)", and the inequality is preserved by subtracting the same amount from both sides.

Comment: oh okay, I'm now understanding things.... :)

Comment: Feel free to ask further in chat! I can give you the precise rules for inequalities if you wish.